# Xampp not uploading images and files

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hey guys I am running a script on my loal sever xampp and i am unable to uplaod images. yes i know, I have increased the max file size in php.ini file etc etc, problem i am facing is , there are 2 php,ini files in the php folder. one is php.ini development and the other is Production. anf there is another php file (setting)

what exactly i am changing?  Whuich file..
The script uploads images well on a live server. not just Xamp..
i have downgraded to xamp with php 5.6, still no luck

Comment: If you create a short script with just `<?php phpinfo();` there will be a line which says something like `Loaded Configuration File` and it gives the full path to the php.ini being used.

Comment: yeah I located the files.changed values, othing happens.. ah well

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be in the PHP code. I added

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
```

to my code, to  move it to the "uploads/" folder from its default temporary location